# The Java Microbenchmark package jdk.incubator does not exist

Tags: java, jvm, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I have an error when i use command line `mvn clean install` when I compile my benchmark

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project jmh-benchmarks: Compilation failure: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/user/jmh/MyBenchmark.java:[11,21] package jdk.incubator does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I passed the parameters with @fork like that :

```java
import jdk.incubator.vector;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(value = 1,jvmArgsAppend = {"--add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector"
})

public class MyBenchmark {
   //My Code ...
}
```

But `jdk.incubator` is not recognized although I passed it in parameters to @Fork
Can someone help me?

Comment: That seems to be on compile, not on running the benchmark - so you issue is with compiler args.

Comment: i see, but i don't have idea how i can fix the problem

Comment: Please show your maven-compiler-plugin configuration. Given `jdk.incubator.vector` is a preview feature, it is only available when compiling *and* running with preview enabled.

Comment: how i can did that  (sohwing my maven-compiler-plugin) ?